# Как узнать url новых открытых окон selenium-а?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем добрый день. Есть скрипт на Python, который переходит на эту страницу https://www.flashscore.ru/ и с помощью Selenium жмет на каждый матч и выводит ссылку от этого матча. Time.sleep для того, чтобы js на странице успевал загрузиться.
Проблема в том, что при нажатии на матч, открывается не новая вкладка, а новое окно браузера, selenium этого нового окна не видит, он всё еще на первоначальной странице https://www.flashscore.ru/ и получается что выводится ссылка изначальной страницы сайта, но не от матча. Как можно брать ссылку с каждого матча? С помощью Selenium или без него? Заранее спасибо.
Код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.ru/')
time.sleep(13)

for channel in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".event__match.event__match--scheduled.event__match--oneLine"):
    channel.click()
    time.sleep(13)

    link = driver.current_url
    print(link)
```

Вывод:

```
https://www.flashscore.ru/
https://www.flashscore.ru/
https://www.flashscore.ru/
https://www.flashscore.ru/
https://www.flashscore.ru/
...
...
https://www.flashscore.ru/
```

А должны быть ссылки от каждого матча в том порядке, в каком Selenium нажимает (т.е. по порядку):

```
https://www.flashscore.ru/match/lUKXoAEo/#match-summary
https://www.flashscore.ru/match/OnDpq8b4/#match-summary
https://www.flashscore.ru/match/llD7mNQ3/#match-summary
...
```

Comment: так и должно быть, что при нажатии открывается новое окно браузера?

Comment: это особенность сайта. При нажатии на любой матч он почему-то открывается в новом браузере, то есть теперь 2 гугл хрома у меня открыто, на одном - сам сайт, в другом хроме - именно страница с матчем (на который нажал)

Comment: и как взять ссылку от именно матча (которое открывается новое окно - непонятно)

Comment: какие-то извращенцы писали этот сайт )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

к сожалению, этот метод работает относительно медленно, т.к. каждый раз приходится загружать данные новооткрытого окна.
я попробовал немного сократить временные затраты с помощью `driver.set_page_load_timeout(0.5)`
Конечно, было бы намного удобнее, если бы можно было бы получить ссылки из html сайта, а не при переходе

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.ru/')
time.sleep(3)

arr = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
    ".event__match.event__match--scheduled.event__match--oneLine"
)


# optional (if you are not satisfied with the download speed)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(0.5)


for channel in arr:
    try:
        channel.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        print("data not received. need more time in driver.set_page_load_timeout")
        continue

    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[arr.index(channel)+1])

    link = driver.current_url
    print(link)
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: Вы очень помогли. Можно ли как-нибудь с Вами связаться? Почта или тг? Огромное спасибо и удачи Вам в жизни!

Comment: подскажите, а почему после 17 матча выводит ошибку: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div id="g_1_GzZFvoYt" title="Подробности матча!" class="event__match event__match--scheduled event__match--last event__match--oneLine">...</div> is not clickable at point (531, 814). Other element would receive the click: <p id="onetrust-policy-text">...</p>` что этот матч не кликабельный (хотя он кликабелен)

Comment: Ну. Selenium сообщает, что в той точке нет кликабельного объекта. Здесь вопрос о том, как вы находите эти объекты. Можно попробовать добавить проверку на кликабельность

Comment: Если вам хочется связаться, можете написать свои контакты тг, я вам отпишусь.